# Minimum sdk adding problem

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a problem about my AndroidManifest.xml. Normally, I didn't have problem with my application. But I wanted to release my app on Android Market and it said you have to add minsdk to your manifest.

Now I added this code to my app but there is no way to install .apk to devices from internet. When I try to send my application to emulator I also start to see force close screen. Do you have any idea about this situation? When I delete minsdk line, there is no problem ./

```
<i><uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/><i>
```

Comment: Could you add the output you see in LogCat when installing the apk? What API level is your emulator running on?

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the logcat
http://i56.tinypic.com/15efww6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `<i>` tags:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

and looking at the picture, you may need also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: There is no italic tag in the manifest (I think it isn't possible to save with <i> tag.) I tried to do my code quote in italic while posting.

Comment: Well, I can say only what I see... check also that you have READ_PHONE_STATE permission in the manifest. It is cut, but the logcat complains about two processes not having that permission

Comment: thank you. Actually, I was looking for a permission problem but I totally forgot my telephony listener. I didn't sleep for a while, and I should take a coffee. Again, thank you for solution.